# How to get odbcexception number

Tags: c#

In sql we have sqlexeption.numer but In odbcexeption we don't have that property,how to get the execption number?

Answer (score 3):

Because more than one error can be encapsulated in an `OdbcException`, you need to iterate through the [Errors property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcexception.errors.aspx):

```
}
catch(OdbcException e)
{
    for (int i=0; i < e.Errors.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Index #{0}", i);
        Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", e.Errors[i].Message);
        Console.WriteLine("NativeError: {0}", e.Errors[i].NativeError.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", e.Errors[i].Source);
        Console.WriteLine("SQL: {0}", e.Errors[i].SQLState);
    }
}
```

(Note that `SqlException` suffers the same problem, it's just that `SqlException.Number` returns the *first* entry in the collection - it's just a wrapper for the loop above, really)

Comment: thks for your answer it is ok,one more thing i want to know is the equivalent error code in odbc exception for sqlexception error code 53 and 2

Comment: Why would there be multiple errors under one odbc exception? Ive even seen same errors repeated multiple times !

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `Errors` collection of the `OdbcException`. Each `OdbcError` has a `NativeError` property.